# How to setup Disk Quotas on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, big-sur, user-account, disk-space

Is there a way to limit a user's disk space usage in macOS Big Sur?

I found this [article to setup disk quotas](https://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-limit-user-disk-space-with-partitions-and-quotas-in-os-x/) from CNET, but apparently it is not working anymore with Big Sur. There are two problems that I discovered:

- The root "/" file system cannot be written on (even with `sudo`).
- Creating the quota files (`.quota.ops.user`) within the `/System/Volumes/Data` directory had no effect in setting up the quota (e.g. running `sudo edquota`) had no output.

Comment: Interesting I was trying to do this same thing yesterday!

Answer (score 3):

You would need to install *quota-tools* from Homebrew and then use that to configure your disk quotas.

Install Homebrew (if you haven't done so already)

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then install `quota-tools`.

```
brew install quota-tools
```

Afterwards edit your `/etc/fstab` to enable disk quotas for the file sytem

```
/dev/rdisk0 /home apfs defaults,usrquota 0 2
```

Then run `edquota` to add disk quotas for the individual users:

```
sudo edquota -p user1 user2
```

After that restart the system to have the disk remounted and disk quota to take effect.

Comment: there is no such brew package. And there is no /etc/fstab file on my mac :(